# Simple Pyramid In C

Tags: c

the code I've written creates a pyramid with given input. I need the first part Incrementing by 2, but the code written does not really Incrementing by 2. Aprrechiate any help.

Code:

```
int main() {

    int i, j, n, a, rows;
    
    printf("Enter a Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    
    printf("\nPattern for %d:\n\n", rows);

    for (i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {

        printf("%d | ", i);

        for(a = 2; a <= i; a+=2) {
            printf("%d ", a);
        }

        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (j == i){ 
                printf("%d ", j);
            }
        }

        for(n = 1; n < i; n++){
            printf("%d ", j);
            j++;
        }
        
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Needed Output:

```
0 | 0
1 | 0 1
2 | 0 2 2 3
3 | 0 2 4 3 4 5
4 | 0 2 4 6 4 5 6 7
5 | 0 2 4 6 8 5 6 7 8 9
6 | 0 2 4 6 8 10 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Current Output:

```
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 2 2 3
3 | 2 3 4 5
4 | 2 4 4 5 6 7
5 | 2 4 5 6 7 8 9
6 | 2 4 6 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: You have *bugs* so use a *debugger* and step through your code.

Comment: Can you identify a *pattern* in how your output differs from the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add an extra if condition for `i = 0` because it was not fitting in the pattern I figured out. I have done it in just 2 loops instead of you using 3 loops.
Here is the brief explanation. Comment on this answer if you don't understand the code still, I will add a detailed explanation.
Case i = 0 is a special case and it is handled separately using an if.
for i > 0, you can notice that there are 2 series in parallel

1. even numbers always starting from 0 and if you count them then they are equal to value of i in that row.
2. another series whose first number is the value of i in that row and it also has number of elements equal to value of i in that row.

That's why in both the loops that handle the series they are run from 0 till i-1.

I hope it helps you and please accept as correct answer if it did.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i, j, n, a, b, c, rows;

printf("Enter a Number: ");
scanf("%d", &rows);

printf("\nPattern for %d:\n\n", rows);

for (i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {

    if(i == 0){
        printf("0 | 0\n");
        continue;
    }
    
    printf("%d | ", i);
    
    // For handling the even number series
    for(a = 0, b = 0; a < i; a++, b+=2) {
        printf("%d ", b);
    }
    // For handling the incremental series
    for (j = 0, c = i; j < i; j++, c++) {
        printf("%d ", c);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to overcomplicate simple task.

```
void pyramid(int rows)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(int even = 0; even < row * 2; even += 2)
        {
            printf("%d ", even);
        }
        if(row == 0) printf("%d ", row);
        else
        {
            for(int remain = row; remain < row * 2; remain++)
            {
                printf("%d ", remain);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cdWqsq